# Limit of sequences, how solve for $N$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, logic

DEFINTION: The sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges to the limits $a\in\mathbb{R}$, if for all $\varepsilon>0$ a positive integer $N$ exists, so that $\left|a_{n}-a\right|<\varepsilon$, is true for all $n \geq N$.

I have to find out what $N$ is. Normally I would simplify $\left|a_{n}-a\right|<\varepsilon$ as far as possible and solve for $n$. My question is: Can we find out the value of $N$ if we can't solve for $n$? (Just imagine $a_n = p_n$, where $p_n$ is the $n$-th prime number. Of course $a_n$ wouldn't converge, but my point  is you can't solve for $n$ in this example. Only if you have a higher or lower boundary, but let's assume we don't have one.)

I have an idea how solve for $N$, but I need you to show me if I'm right:

1. Let's just assume that there is a $N$ and $\left|a_{n}-a\right|<\varepsilon$ holds for all $n\geq N$.
2. You can do some calculations and derive to your wanted expression. (Expression does not matter)
3. You test values for $n$ in this expression. For example set $n=1$, and it doesn't work. After that you set $n=2$ and it does work.

Q1: If the expression holds for $n=x$, where $x$ is a postive integer, does it mean that the expression also holds for $n\geq x$?

Q2: If the expression doesn't hold for $n = x$ but it holds for $n=x+1$, is $N=x+1$?

Comment: Remember, you don't necessarily need to *solve* for $N$.  You just need a value of $N$ that's "good enough."  That means you can (sometimes) rely on estimates and inequalities that result in an $N$ that may be larger than you needed.  This is easier to explain, of course, with a concrete example.

Comment: This is a totally different question from the one I answered.  If you have a different question, please ask it separately.  Please roll it back.

Answer (score 2):

Testing for values does not work because an early value might be very close to the limit but later values are farther away.  We could have the sequence $1,1,1,3,5,34434342,1-2^{-n}$ where $n$ starts from $1$ in the first term that includes it and increases.  Clearly the limit is $1$, but you would find $n=1,2,3$ all are within $\epsilon$ of the limit but as long as $\epsilon \lt 2$ the next three terms are not.  We could even modify that sequence by changing $a_{1000000}$ to $12345$ and not change the limit.  In that case for any reasonable $\epsilon$ you need $N$ to be at least $1000001$  This shows the answer to Q1 is no.  Similarly Q2 is no as my modified example shows.

You don't have to find the minimum $N$ that works, you just have to find one that does for a given $\epsilon$.  If a certain $N$ works, so does $N'=N+1000000$  If it is easier to prove that the larger one works, use it and you are done.  For example, suppose we are summing the inverse squares of the primes.  To prove this sum converges, we can just say that each term is less than the corresponding sum of the inverse squares of all the naturals, which we know converges.  If I knew the $N$ in the second one corresponding to a given $\epsilon$, I could use it for the first as well.